# Cannot run JUnit test from Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, junit

I'm trying to run some JUnit 4 tests from an Eclipse plugin, but I'll only get the following failure:

> initializationError(testpkg.TestClass): No runnable methods

The test class is really simple:

```
package testpkg;
(...)
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test run");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When I run it programmatically in a simple java project, it works, but not in an Eclipse plugin:

```
    public class DiscoverHandler extends AbstractHandler {
        @Override
        public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
            (...)
            File file = new File("C:(...)\\target\\test-classes"); //The .class file
            URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] file.toURI().toURL()});
            JUnitCore.runClasses(classLoader.loadClass("testpkg.TestClass")).getFailures().forEach(c -> System.out.println(c.toString()));
        }
    }
```

The same code in a simple Java Project will actually print the "Test run" String.

Does anyone knows where this error might come from ?
Thank you

Comment: When you debug your code: Does it as plug-in find the class? Sometimes I got trouble with pathes out of plug-ins.

Comment: Yes, using File.exists(), or even the ClassLoader.loadClass("testpkg.TestClass") will return the right Class<?> object, with its test() method. 

Also I'm able to launch the test configuration using      DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunchConfigurations()[1].launch(org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null);

But that's not what I want

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to do it, by doing this:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()}, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Instead of this :

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] file.toURI().toURL()});
```

I can't explain why this is working though. If anyone has the answer, I would gladly know it.